# i am trying to connect a login page to the remote sql database and StrictMode error emerges

Tags: android

```
package com.efas.admin.efasrestaurant;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText Username;
  EditText Password;
  Button button1;
Button button2;
Connection connect;
SimpleAdapter AD;

  private Connection CONN(String _user , String _pass , String _DB , String _server){

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    Connection Conn=null;
    String connString;
    try{
        connect = CONN("sa", "123456789", "EFAS", "192.168.0.101");
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip_address :192.168.0.101/EFAS;encrypt=fasle;user=sa;password=123456789;instance=BLAZE;";
        Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connString);
        Log.w("Connection","open");
        Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery("select * from UserName");
        Statement stmt1 = Conn.createStatement();
        stmt1.executeQuery("select * from UserPassword");

    }catch (SQLException se){
        Log.e("ERROR",se.getMessage());
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
    }
    return CONN(_user, _pass, _DB, _server);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);
    Username=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
    Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text2);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Username.getText().toString().equals("stmt")&&
                Password.getText().toString().equals("stmt1")) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this, "Username and Password is correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text1);
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TableLists.class);
                i.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
                startActivity(i);
            } else
            {Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"Please Enter a Valid Username and Password ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(LoginPage.this,"And Try Again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EFAS.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
public String getMacAddress(Context context){
    WifiManager wifiManager=(WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    String macAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
    if (macAddress == null) {
        macAddress = "Device don't have mac address or wi-fi is disabled";
    }
    return macAddress;
}
```

}

when i enter username as stmt and password as stmt1 then the next activity starts but it is supposed to  take username and password input from the database
and it is not happining when i enter the username and password of the database it goes to else condition how can i fix this ???

Comment: use `new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy` not `new StrictMode().ThreadPolicy`

Comment: new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();   done this bt the entire code might have an error it is not connected to the database can you plz figure it out

Comment: And what is that error?

Comment: the app will not connect to the sql server and donot check the username and password how can i do that ???

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskWrites().penaltyLog().build());
```